# Bootstrap modal

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-modal

Problem is, whenever I try to echo variables I got from contact form with PHP code in bootstrap modal, they just don't appear. Here is the code:

## Contact

```
        <form class="contact-form" action="" method="post">

            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"></br>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr; ?></span></br></br>


            <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="E-mail" value="<?php echo $mail; ?>"></br>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $mailErr; ?></span></br></br>


            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" value="<?php echo $message; ?>" ></textarea></br>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $messageErr; ?></span></br></br>
            <button formtarget="_blank" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">Send</button></br>
        </form>
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 style="color:black;" class="modal-title">Message</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p style="color:black;">
                            <?php
                            echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
                            echo $name;
                            echo "<br>";
                            echo $mail;
                            echo "<br>";
                            echo "<br>";
                            echo $message;
                            ?>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

////Random text for avoiding the site error;sorry
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Here is PHP code:

```
<?php
    $nameErr = $mailErr = $messageErr = "";
    $name = $mail = $message = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
            $nameErr = "*Name is required";
        } else {
            $name = check($_POST["name"]);
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name)) {
                $nameErr = "*Only letters and white spaces allowed";
            }
        }
        if (empty($_POST["mail"])) {
            $mailErr = "*E-mail is required";
        } else {
            $mail = check($_POST["mail"]);
            if (!filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $mailErr = "*Invalid E-mail format";
            }
        }
        if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
            $messageErr = "*Message is required";
        } else {
            $message = check($_POST["message"]);
        }
    }

    function check($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Those variables would be stored in the `$_POST` array, not by name as you have in your example. You can access them as `$_POST['fieldname']`, e.g., `$_POST['name']`

Comment: Well now when I rewrote it like you said, this is the message that I get:
Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\Kolokvijum\index.php on line 162

Comment: The question-tag is too general and makes no sense. Modify it to reflect your issue much better. Also remove the googol "A". Community bot might swing his viking axe if you don't ;p

Comment: Show us your PHP code...

Comment: It's good practice to check whether `$_POST` variables are set before you try echoing them. Before the form is submitted the index would be undefined. You could use `if (isset($_POST))` to check if the form was submitted, or the individual fields with `if (isset($_POST['fieldname']))`. I also like to use `if ( strlen($_POST['filedname']))` to make sure the field was not submitted as an empty string

Comment: try using isset(). like this @tshimkus said. `isset($_POST['name'])? $_POST['name'] : "" ;`

Comment: I did that and it returns an empty string.

Comment: Thanks for including the form processing PHP. That provides much better context of the problem. One of the problems with using `isset()` on its own with post variables is that it will return true for empty strings. Is the PHP code executed above the html part where you are trying to echo the values?

Comment: Yes it is actually.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
   <div class="modal-content" role="document">
   ...
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a google search for "showing dynamic content in bootstrap modal"